# Move position of end tag dynamically in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

The solution to this one feels like it's on the tip of my tongue, but I can't quite figure out a way to do it. Consider the following HTML:

```
<span>This has some text.
    <span>This has some more text.</span>
    <span>And so on.</span>
    <span>And so forth, et cetera, et cetera, et cetera...</span>
</span>
```

Each span has a click listener:

```
$("span").click(function()
{
    $(this).css("color", "somecolor");
}
```

When the PARENT span has its css changed, is there a way to prevent the css change from propagating to the children elements?  Or a way to only make the change affect the TEXT in the clicked span?

I know there are ways of reorganizing the html that would make it easier, but I'm dealing with very malformed html automatically generated by a legacy system I can't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a word, no. This is the "cascading" part of CSS in action.

You'll have to add CSS specifically to undo the change done to those child elements. For instance:

```
$("span").click(function() {
    $(this).css("color", "blue")
        .children().css("color","black");
});
```

Depending on exactly what your HTML looks like, you may need to stop the click from propagating up to the outermost `span` as well:

```
$("span").click(function() {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).css("color", "blue")
        .children().css("color","black");
});
```

A possibly less-complicated solution involves using `!important` to nail down the CSS styles of the sub-`span`s: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/ce2Av/2/
 However, you'll need to specify *all* the sub-elements of that outer span in this manner, which may get complicated depending on your HTML.

If you want the children not to be all one color, but to remain whatever color they were beforehand, then things get tricky. You'd have to cache those values beforehand using an array and then reassign them one by one.

Comment: I ended up having to do just what you say in the last paragraph.  I didn't want it to come to that, but it looks like there just isn't any other way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On click stop event propagation and add some class to span. In CSS create two rules - general for span and another for class. Child elements will not be affected on click.

Javascript

```
$("span").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).addClass("special");
});
```

CSS

```
span{
    color:#DDD;
}
.special{
    color:#0077cc;
}
```